# Logging into Google Apps Extension Console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script

Here the documention[1] says that to log-in to Google Apps Extension Console, I need to type this:

```
http://code.google.com/googleapps/console/a/yourDomainName[2]
```

Now my question is:

What does yourDomainName imply? I made a project in Google Apps but when I replace its name with yourDomainName, the link goes into infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's meant to be used by Google Apps customers only (companies that pay for Google Apps for Business or Education).

```
http://code.google.com/googleapps/console/a/examplecompany.com
```